# Display STL file web

Tags: laravel, three.js, 3d, webgl

I'm working on a web application, using laravel, and I have to display stl files within a slider. So far I have been using png pictures to build the rest and deal with the 3d part later. But later has come, eventually.

For now, the user uploads its png/jpeg file and it goes straight to my 'public/storage/images/' folder. Then it is displayed within the slider, on another view.

I now need to replace those basic pictures with stl file and I am not sure on how to do that.

I wanted to use Three.js but my manager would like something easier (no need to use parameters), like a basic viewer, since **there's no need to interact with the obj**, yet.

Having to deal with 3D is new to me so I am a little bit confused on how to approach it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with this? http://webglsamples.org/

Comment: Nothing, I had WebGL and three.js in mind but I think what my manager is looking for is a way to display a 3d obj without having to parse it  so that I don't "lose time", so to speak.